# Need help using Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, loopbackjs

```
var leftpanefilter = {
    "organization": [],
    "speciality": [],
    "city": []
};

dataSource.connector.query(getCitySQL, function(err, citylist) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error getting citylist");
    } else {
        try {
            for (var i = 0; i < citylist.length; i++) {
                leftpanefilter.city.push(citylist[i].name);
            }
            // callback(null, leftpanefilter);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
});

// Get list of organization which has openings
dataSource.connector.query(getOrgSQL, function(err, organizationlist) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error getting organizationlist");
    } else {
        try {
            for (var i = 0; i < organizationlist.length; i++) {
                leftpanefilter.organization.push(organizationlist[i].name);
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
});

// Get list of specialities associated with openings
dataSource.connector.query(getCitySQL, function(err, specialitylist) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error getting specialitylist");
    } else {
        try {
            for (var i = 0; i < specialitylist.length; i++) {
                leftpanefilter.speciality.push(specialitylist[i].name);
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
});

callback(null, leftpanefilter);
```

Because of the Async nature of Nodejs, the callback returns blank data without waiting for queries to execute. Does anyone know how to use a promise to get the output with data from the queries? I can't figure out how to make node to wait until all the queries are finished.

Comment: Promises isn't the panacea for asynchronous coding

Comment: It might not be, but it could surely help OP in this case (after having a really quick look).

Answer (score 0):

As an example of what 'could' work in this case:

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    dataSource.connector.query(getCitySQL, function(err, callback) {
        if (err) {
            reject(err)
        }
        else {
            resolve(callback)
        }
    })
}).then(function(specialitylist) {
    for (var i = 0; i < specialitylist.length; i++) {
        leftpanefilter.speciality.push(specialitylist[i].name);
    }    
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Something went wrong!')
    console.log(err)
});
```

**What am I doing here?**

I'm creating a new promise before I query the database, which has two parameters, a resolve (when the db succesfully sends the callback) and a reject (when an error appears).

The `.then()` function then takes the output of resolve, and continues the operation for whatever you wish to do with your data.

The `.catch()` function is there to deal with any errors or problems that might occur while you're coding.

I suppose this could help you on your way for now, let me know if you have any other questions

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use Promises in this case like

```
var queryPromise = function(dataSource, sql, list) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        dataSource.connector.query(sql, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                reject("Error getting " + list);
            }
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
};

Promise.all([
    queryPromise(dataSource, getCitySQL, 'citylist'),
    queryPromise(dataSource, getOrgSQL, 'organizationlist'),
    queryPromise(dataSource, getCitySQL, 'specialitylist')
]).then(function(results) {
    callback(null, {
        city: results[0],
        organization: results[1],
        speciality: results[2]
    });
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

This has no error checking as I don't know what you would do in your examples case anyway

This also replaces ALL the code you've posted - no need to predefine the `leftpanefilter`

NOTE: with promise all, any one of those calls fails, the whole thing is "rejected" - and callback will never be called - of course you can change that yourself, but as you've provided no information about what callback does, I can only speculate so wont do so here

> NOTE: specialtylist SQL is the same as city? typo on your part?

A slightly different approach

```
var queryPromise = function(dataSource, sql, list) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        dataSource.connector.query(sql, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                resolve({error: "Error getting " + list});
            }
            resolve({data: data});
        });
    });
};

Promise.all([
    queryPromise(dataSource, getCitySQL, 'citylist'),
    queryPromise(dataSource, getOrgSQL, 'organizationlist'),
    queryPromise(dataSource, getCitySQL, 'specialitylist')
]).then(function(results) {
    callback(null, {
        city: results[0].data || results[0].error,
        organization: results[1].data || results[1].error,
        speciality: results[2].data || results[2].error
    });
});
```

in this case there is no "reject"ion so, Promise.all will always resolve. The values in the data sent to the `callback` will either be an array, or a string in the case of an error - so, error checking can be done in the callback

Comment: This is very good, but has a small catch. What if I have to use data from an earlier promise to create my next promise? (if there's a really simple solution / I misread the code, please feel free to correct me).

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, or how it relates to the actual question posed :p

Comment: I'm drifting off a bit yes, i've been using a system of promises as well for the past weeks (in a simular node.js) environment. Your solution looks really neat, but my sub-question would be: 'How can I use the callback of my first promise to construct a query I wrap in a second promise? while using your `Promise.all()` method?

Comment: You wouldn't for sequential promises like that